# Need some help to parse data in string

Tags: php

I try to extract data to build string,this is my code

```
// there are 280 $combination

foreach ($combinations as $combination) {

    $optionsArray = explode('|', $combination->associate_options);

    foreach ($optionsArray as $optionID) {


        $option = OptionsValues::Where('seller_optionvalues_key', $optionID)->first();
        if ($option->option_name <> $tmpName) {
            $optionslist = $option->option_name .':';
        }
        if ($option->option_name <> $tmpValue) {
            $optionslist .= $option->value;
            if ($option->option_name <> $tmpName) {
                $optionslist .= ']},';
            }
            $array1[$option->option_name] = $option->value;
            array_push($data,$array1);

        }

    }
```

i try to get all option name without duplciate content with corresponding values without duplicate content, using my code i get array from all but keys are duplicate and values are duplicated.I don't know how to parse array or if exist better methode to do that.

- option1 : value1|value2|value3|etc
- option2 : value4|value5|value6|etc

Thanks for help

Comment: Is this a framework that you are working with? Is the `OptionsValues::Where` a DB call?

Comment: what's `$tmpName`?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input value and the current and expected output?

Comment: Looks as though you are trying to generate JSON, there may be a more direct way if there was some data to test with.